# Ionic2: exception nativeEvalAndFetch: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to run my Ionic 2 app in the emulator with this command:

```
ionic emulate ios
```

But I get a screen of death (white screen). I tried to debug the app with the Safari developer tools and I am getting these information:

[image]

> exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

[image]

The directory in the CoreSimulator looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you running any cordova plugins? If yes, it must be run on a physical device and not on emulator

Comment: Yes, I am using several plugins: "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"

But it is also not possible to view the app in the Ionic View app. Normally cordova logs a message to the console, that the app is currently running in "emulator or web" version but there is no error.

Comment: Mind showing your index.html code?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with remove the:

```
<base href="/">
```

from the index.html